# Android project SVN out of date error. Updating and rechecking out project does not solve the issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

Note: I'm new to Stack Overflow. This is my first question. Let me know if I don't post the question correctly, or if I'm missing something that needs to be added in to the explanation.

I'm on a team that has an android project that is running into an SVN out of date error. The out of date error occurs whenever we try and commit our project changes.

We have tried updating the project at the file we are changing and at the head and the out of date error persists. We have tried checking the project out on different computers and the error still occurs. We have tried using subclipse, and SmartSVN and the error still occurs.

The original creator can update and commit changes with out getting the out of date error.

We have tried just about everything we have seen searching through google. As stated before we have tried updating the project, checking it our brand new, and everything that should work, but none of it seems to make the out of date error go away.

The following is a few other things we have found in our efforts:

1 - It does not seem to be an eclipse problem. I made a change in TextEdit on the project after freshly checking it out from the repository, the same out of date error occurred when trying to commit the change via SmartSVN.

2 - Deleting the following .SVN folder files did not fix the problem

- svn.867f2d17-4301-0010-8283-dd8934b422cc.tmp
- wc.db.smartsvn-backup-1387663284-000000256443-000000256443-SvnUpdate.pre
- wc.db.smartsvn-backup-1387663284-000000259034-000000259034-SvnUpdate.post
- wc.db
- smartsvn.properties and validating with SmartSVN
- smartsvn.properties without validating with SmartSVN
- format
- entries
- pristine folder
- temp folder

3 - I changed a single file and then updated it recursively then tried committing it. Still got the out of date error.

4 - Updating the same file non-recursively then committed it. Still got out of date error.

5 - Saved a text file in the top level of the directory outside of the android project folders that says “hi” on the inside. Added to the repository, committed, opened it and made a change so it read “hello world”, committed, and it works.

6 - Removed the text file from the svn, moved it to a file inside of the android project, added to svn, committed, get out of date error

7 - The .svn folder is not in the bin folder of the Android project, so I don't think the bin folder is causing a problem like it can sometimes do with repositories.

---

Error Message Output from Subclipse -

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E160024: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160024: File or directory 'averikWebAPI.java' is out of date; try updating
svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT of '/svn/averik/!svn/ver/20/averik%20Rewards%20Android/src/com/averik/rewards/web/averikWebAPI.java': 409 Conflict (http://clever.com)
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E160024: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160024: File or directory 'averikWebAPI.java' is out of date; try updating
svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT of '/svn/averik/!svn/ver/20/averik%20Rewards%20Android/src/com/averik/rewards/web/averikWebAPI.java': 409 Conflict (http://clever.com)

---

Error message from Smart SVN -

**An error occured while processing an SVN command.**
Commit failed(details follow): File'/Users/Isaac/root/WorkHard/averik/averikRewards/src/com/averik/rewards/web/averikWebAPI.java'is out of date

Comment: I guess you could try removing it from the repo and adding it back?

Comment: Can you give the exact error message text? It could provide a clue.

Comment: @Ben, I edited my question to include the error message outputs given by Subclipse and Smart SVN.

Comment: Very strange. I think I'd have tried the same fixes (fresh checkouts on different computers, `svn update`) but those didn't help, you said. Are you and the original author using the same SVN version? Which one? Maybe try using the SVN command-line tools to see if those work. At least then it's easy to tell which version you have.

Comment: An `svn update` should resolve this problem. If it doesn't, then it should give you an error. In that case please paste the error into your question.

Comment: @Janos - An svn update works fine. It does not give an error message. It also does not resolve the problem. I was thinking of maybe doing a screen cast to show the steps I'm doing in a vid. Would that be a good idea?

Comment: @Ben The original author and I are using the same SVN version. I will try using SVN command-line tools and let you know how that goes.